# Package dependencies cannot be resolved in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: updates, package-management

currently I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Whenever I am trying to install any package form ubuntu software center I am getting the following message "Package dependencies cannot be resolved".
And also from the update center it is not showing any update information. Is there any permanent solution?
For information I have tried the commands like "sudo apt-get clean" and "sudo apt-get update". But the its not working as I am getting the message repeatedly.
what can I do? Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

Go to ubuntu software center >> Edit >> Software Sources >> Download From >> Select United States After that restart your computer go to software center and type your softare name and install it.

OR ELSE

Try this

```
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install wine -y
```

replace `wine` with your software name.

Comment: I had a slightly different issue with a pending security update for an EOL version of Ubuntu (namely, 14.04) and running the first three commands fixed it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Synaptic. Download it offline i..e .deb file and install. During install, it will ask you for some library files. Download those also manually.
Copy all .deb files in one folder and then run the command:
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Once done, start synaptic by typing sudo synaptic in terminal.
If you install software through this, then very less chance that such errors will come. Also it will help you resolve the existing errors.

Synaptic is suggested for beginners than using command lines in terminals.